# How can I access the font of selected, Outlook Web Add-in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

In the Word Web Add-in I can access font of the selected `context.document.getSelection().font` but I don't find it (after searching too) in Outlook Web Add-in, I only can get the text of selected by `Office.context.mailbox.item.getSelectedDataAsync` with `Office.CoercionType.Text` parameter, How can I get the font please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text formatting in Outlook is done in HTML (assuming the format isn't plain text). You can return the underlying HTML using `Office.CoercionType.Html`:

```
Office.initialize = function () {
    Office.context.mailbox.item
        .getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, {},
            function (asyncResult) {
                var htmlData = asyncResult.value.data;
                // do stuff
            });
}
```

Since the HTML formatting might have been set outside the scope of your selection, you might want to grab the entire body as well. You can then use the `getSelectedDataAsync` results to find the current selection within the full HTML body:

```
function myFunction() {

    // Get the selected text
    Office.context.mailbox.item
        .getSelectedDataAsync('html', {}, function (asyncResult) {

            // Get the full body and pass through the selectedData
            // in the asyncContext. 
            Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", {
                    asyncContext: asyncResult.value.data
                },
                function callback(asyncResult) {
                    // Get the body from the result
                    let bodyDaya = asyncResult.value.data;

                    // Get the selectedData we passed in
                    let selectedData = asyncResult.asyncContext;

                    // Do stuff
                });

        });
}
```

Comment: Please excuse me for being beginner at office.js , I have used `Office.CoercionType.Html` instead and tried `asyncResult.value.data.font.bold=true;` , `asyncResult.value.data.font.Bold=true;` , `asyncResult.value.data.bold=true;` and `asyncResult.value.data.Bold=true;` but they all didn't work, Shall I do it in another way?

Comment: `asyncResult.value.data` is a `string` containing `html` markup, not an object. You'll need to parse the `html` to determine what `style` is being applied. Take a look at [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) as a potential option.